# How to make a model that identify that it is something specific?

Tags: deep-learning, identify

How to I make the model that identify that it is something specific? (Deep learning)

For example,
like if the input value is greater than 20, output will be [0, 1]
and value is less than 20, it will be [1, 0].

Can anyone help?

Comment: this is an unclear and vague question with no real answer for you. You would not need a deep learning model for this particular question (nor machine learning). I doubt the real question would make a good question for this forum either.

Comment: This is just an example and I will try to make something more complicated.

Comment: Add layers, nodes will make the model learn different attributes, to make it learn something specific will require tuning - difficult to help without knowing the situation. For example a simple NN allows things like the `xor` operation to be detected